# How To add duplicate search box to jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

In [This](http://onlytesttomyblog.blogspot.in/) blog i have created sucessfully jquery autocomplete with search button sucessfully. But i want just like [This](http://www.indeed.co.in/)

My searchbox aim to select tags-> redirect to another page..

my problem is i want to add one more search box with one button only i mean search fields i mean search areas should be 2 with same links and i mean i modify the links like zipcode links and city links later but i presently need one search button with multiple search areas i hope my question is clear and the above is my code

```js
   var selectedItemUrl = "";
   $(function() {
     var source = [{
       value: "NYC",
       url: 'http://www.nyc.com'
     }, {
       value: "LA",
       url: 'http://www.la.com'
     }, {
       value: "Philly",
       url: 'http://www.philly.com'
     }, {
       value: "Chitown",
       url: 'http://www.chitown.com'
     }, {
       value: "DC",
       url: 'http://www.washingtondc.com'
     }, {
       value: "SF",
       url: 'http://www.sanfran.com'
     }, {
       value: "Peru",
       url: 'http://www.peru.com'
     }];

     $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
       minLength: 0,
       source: source,
       select: function(event, ui) {
         selectedItemUrl = ui.item.url
       }
     })

   });

   function SearchItem(e) {
     if (selectedItemUrl != "")
       window.location = selectedItemUrl
     else
       alert("select something to search")
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="autocomplete" />
<button onclick='SearchItem()'>search
```

Comment: Not clear what exactly u want to achieve

Comment: like this http://www.indeed.co.in/ i need i mean only one button with different search fields i have already added one search field with one button but not able to add another search field with links as i explained above

Comment: You should not open multiple links from JS, it could easily be blocked by end-user browser.

Comment: my aim is to add multiple links to multiple boxes not adding from js right......?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

Whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
 var selectedItemUrl1=null
  var selectedItemUrl2=null

     $(function () {
    var source = [{
        value: "NYC",
        url: 'http://www.nyc.com'
    }, {
        value: "LA",
        url: 'http://www.la.com'
    }, {
        value: "Philly",
        url: 'http://www.philly.com'
    }, {
        value: "Chitown",
        url: 'http://www.chitown.com'
    }, {
        value: "DC",
        url: 'http://www.washingtondc.com'
    }, {
        value: "SF",
        url: 'http://www.sanfran.com'
    }, {
        value: "Peru",
        url: 'http://www.peru.com'
    }];

    var source2 = [ {
        value: "LA",
        url: 'http://www.la.com'
    }];

    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: source,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            selectedItemUrl1 = ui.item.url
        }
    })

    $("#autocomplete2").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: source2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            selectedItemUrl2 = ui.item.url
        }
    })

});

function SearchItem(e) {
    if (selectedItemUrl1.indexOf("http") != -1 && selectedItemUrl2.indexOf("http") != -1) {
        if (selectedItemUrl1 != "" && selectedItemUrl2 != "") {
            $("#output").append("<div ><object style='heigth:600px;width:600px;float:left' data='" + selectedItemUrl1 + "'/></div>");
            $("#output").append("<div ><object style='heigth:600px;width:600px;float:left' data='" + selectedItemUrl2 + "'/></div>");


        }
    }

}
```

```
</head>
<body>
    <input id="autocomplete" />
    <input id="autocomplete2" />
    <button onclick='SearchItem()'>search</button>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: added but unable to get http://jquerytest2.blogspot.in/ @patilprashant6792

Comment: no response from search box when i clicked search box after selecting just see http://jquerytest2.blogspot.in/ @patilprashant6792

Comment: it is popup in another window but able to produce in same window ........?

Comment: how do you want to open multiple URLs in same window?? any idea??

Comment: patilprashant you not get me u know about labels in blog spot can we display multiple labels in same window

Comment: like this http://pootih.blogspot.in/search/label/2%20Column+2%20Left%20Sidebar+Blue+Bookmark%20Ready if you select any and filter it will display like that i want to select from autocomplete and display those in same window iam right.....?

Comment: Do you want to redirect to same the Url specified? or you want to reander the html in the same page?

Comment: prashant my aim is to create http://www.indeed.co.in/ in blogger like that text bar so and i want to see all links like above code you have only shown links for autocomplete 1 but you have just coded for the autocomplete 2 but my aim is when ever i want to add 2 links to 2 bars i want to add one another link to 1 bar and another link to another text area and both should display in same window did u got......me .......?

Comment: you are right the way but the main thing is you have only coded links for autocomplete 1 but i want to see the links for autocomplete 2 and also i want to show it in same page with same links i mean la.com link should be seen 2 times in the code .........i hope you understand my problem

Comment: dude are you asking a solution doubt or the whole solution? and secondly i have used same source for both the auto complete. so you can use other source if you want for the second auto complete

Comment: dude thanks you are at the 90% but show links for autocomplete 2 also in the code and render it in the same page i mean the la.com iam seeing one in the code for autocomplete 1 iam right....? same do it for autocomplete 2 also sir...... like this i want to make www.indeed.co.in

Comment: aah well the code which i provided is just a prototype. How is this possible that you cant make other source for other autocomplete sir? you can atleast try to modify your code once instead of updating the requirement and every single thing in the comments?

Comment: i can understand sir but iam new to coding that is y iam unable to understand last one please put duplicate links i mean la.com for autocomplete 2 also it would help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Last Update from my side. If it dosent helps m not you guy